# Ties for students

Tags: proof-of-ties

I am Rainer from Uganda, 32 years old, doing a diploma in Registered Nursing in my last year. I have been invited to attend a training seminar for leaders, and the organization in me will cater for my living expenses. However, I have ever faced a visa rejection on ties issues. One, I want to provide ties since last time I didn't submit them. Can I use my college letter and transcript as a tie to my country?

Second, how can I show family ties since I am not married?